# Relativistic momentum finding

Tags: special-relativity

Kinetic energy of an object $mc^2$. I want to evaluate the momentum.
We know  Kinetic energy, 
$$E_k = \frac{p^2}{2m}$$
$$mc^2 = \frac{p^2}{2m}$$
$$ p = \sqrt{2}mc$$

Note that the momentum is the relativistic mometum. Is there anything I did worng?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: There are a number of mistakes here: $E_k\neq \frac{p^2}{2m}$, $E_k\neq mc^2$.

Answer (score 1):

The formula goes like this 
$$ E^2 = (p^2c^2 + m_0^2c^4) $$  where $m_0$ is the rest mass of the particle. If it is given, that the KE is $$E_k = m_0c^2$$, then you can write,
$$ (2m_0c^2)^2 = (p^2c^2 + m_0^2c^4)  $$ (one $ m_0c^2 $ for rest energy and the other for KE). and then calculate $p$.

Answer (score 0):

mc2 is not the kinetic energy of an object but the rest energy. You cannot combine a rest energy equation with a kinetic energy equation.